# Parse JSON return exception

Tags: c#

I tried to parse JSON using Newtonsoft.Json but no luck. I have following JSON

Here is my json that i want to convert e.g. MyJson

and i want to get createdText.I tried with following code

```
public class Parse
{
    public string createdText { get; set; }
}
var ParsedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parse>(MyJson).createdText;
```

Exception

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

So i upload whole JSON.
Also i want to include foreach to get all fields with name createdText
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The JSON you have provided is not complete and hence not valid, making trying to help you extremely difficult.   Also, there are 3 places where createdText appears in the JSON, so you need to be more specific about which one you actually wish to retrieve.

Comment: Post complete JSON file to look at the issue.

Comment: @dotnetmirror.com Done!

Answer (score 1):

btw: The JSON looks cluncky.. shuld start { or [

Why don't you create a class to represent your value.

```
public class Solution {
  public Title Title {get;set;}
}

public class Title {
   Public TextItem Text {get;set;}
}

public class TextItem {
  public string CreatedText {get;set;}
}

var response =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Solution>(MyResponse)
```

Comment: return exception System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'